# Flutter Responsive Grid List scroll disable

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I made many responsive grids for better user experience and I got a problem with scroll. In grid section appears nested scroll, but un scrollable. And this nested scroll  interfere to my all page to make scroll. How can I[image] solve this problem?

Comment: before you scroll the alignment is right ?

Comment: Its always right. The problem is, hat nested scroll does not allow, to scrolle whole page

Comment: I think you should again rewrite the question in a proper manner and share the code which you have worked on.
the question is not clear to us.

Comment: for solve problem need your code.